# Query to extracting the 14th date from a date after excluding the sunday and saturday in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need a query to extract the 14th day or any other day before a day after excluding Saturday and Sunday in Postgresql.

For Example, I need 14th day before 2020-01-30 after excluding Saturday and Sunday.

Date Dimension  is " YYYY-MM-DD"

I am using 'ISODOW' < 6 condition to exclude Sunday and Saturday. But from the count,  i am not sure how to fetch the date

```
 extract('ISODOW' FROM the_day) < 6
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have a [date dimension](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/calendar-date-dimension/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cand AS (
   SELECT DATE '2020-01-30' - i AS d
   FROM generate_series(1, 2*14+3) AS i
)
SELECT d
FROM cand
WHERE extract(isodow FROM d::timestamp) < 6
ORDER BY d DESC
OFFSET 13
LIMIT 1;
```

The 2*14+3 in the CTE is a safe upper limit and can be improved.